# can't use local json file from my project in $http.get() function

Tags: angularjs, http-get

I have this code but it keeps giving me an error

```
app.controller('myController',["$scope", '$location', '$http', '$rootScope',function($scope, $location, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    paginationPageSize: 15,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'الاسم' },
      { name: 'الجنس' },
      { name: 'الشركة' }
    ]
  };
  $http.get('/data/mydata.json')
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
  })
```

[image: this is the error:]
and this here is my json file:

```
[
{
    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},{

    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "سمير",
    "العائلة": "سمراوي",
    "العمر": "32",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "حمدان",
    "العائلة": "ابو حميد",
    "العمر": "20",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
},
{
    "الاسم": "خالد",
    "العائلة": "خلدون",
    "العمر": "15",
    "الجنس": "ذكر"
}
];
```

the file is called `mydata.json`.
'pardon the language difference'.
What I think my problem is is that I'm not using `$http.get()` function the right way. I'm not sure weather I can use $http.get() for local urls.
Please help and thank you in advance

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/P0HQeO2rGerVquLrARSm?p=preview

Comment: Sorry but I tried you're solution to it and it still didn't work, it didn't change anything, I still have the same error, any other ideas? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

remove the semicolon in the last line in your JSON file.

Also, data comes under `data` property. use `data.data`

```
$http.get('/mydata.json')
  .then(function (data.data) {
    $scope.gridOptions1.data = data.data;
  });
```

Comment: When I use .then(function (data.data)  it gives me an extra error:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." and it doesn't solve the first one

Answer (score 1):

you can find your required object in `data.data`
try using error call back like this to catch the error

```
$http.get('/mydata.json')
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
  },function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it only added a new error!! any other ideas on how I could solve this, thanks for the help (y)

Comment: what error did u get.? i got it alright when i tried. can us show the eroor

Comment: with pleasure: FileJS.js:187 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: can u give screenshots of the code?..and the error. what you are providing is not sufficient

Comment: I just edited the question because it's easier to add code and screenshots there so please go check it out

Comment: did u try using error call back like above? Is your Json file inside the data folder?